# Travis cli installation fails on mac

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci, macos-mojave, travis-ci-cli

Attempt to install travis cli using `sudo gem install travis -v 1.8.9 --no-rdoc --no-ri` generates the following error logs:

```
"pkg-config --exists libffi"
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin18 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe -DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L.     -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

It seems few of the dependencies are missing. How do I install them correctly? I am currently using macos mojave 10.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to install travis using ruby that comes builtin with xcode command line developer tools but installing ruby using `brew install ruby` followed by `sudo gem install travis -v 1.8.9 --no-rdoc --no-ri` resulted in a successful travis installation.

NOTE: You may need to add travis gem to your system path.

Answer (score 20):

`brew install travis` worked for me. I found it [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2055#issuecomment-459869338)